# Read js source code of a script loaded via a src attribute

Tags: javascript, tags

I want to read the js source code of a script loaded via a src attribute with pure javascript.

Like from a html script tag:

```
<script id=myFile type="text/javascript" src="file.js"></script>

var code = document.getElementById('myFile').textContent
```

But the above doesn't work.

This works however :

```
<script id=myFile>
    console.log("This works");
</script>

var code = document.getElementById('myFile').textContent
```

Now, *code* contains "console.log("This works");"

Does somebody know how i can archive this with a js file loaded, instead of writing the js code in the html file?

Answer (score 1):

There is no API to read the source code of a script loaded via a `src` attribute. The only way to access it is to make another HTTP request to that URL (e.g. with `fetch` or `XMLHttpRequest`).

Answer (score 1):

Event though that you can attach a `load` listener to a `<scritp async src="..."></>`, there's no way to access the plain text of the loaded object.

You will need to fetch your script manually and reading the content of it. You can do that with the following:

```
fetch('path/to/script')
  .then(res => {
    return res.text();
  })
  .then(text => {
    console.log(text);
  });
```